# Spread custom tick labels evenly over colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I'm trying to add a custom colorbar to my heatmap using pyplot.
My code looks something like this:

```
c_map = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#c7e9b4','#7fcdbb','#ffffff','#41b6c4','#225ea8','#253494'])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_map)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.arange(6), label='Change in user population')
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['<=-6', '<= -1', '0', '<= 3', '<= 6', '7>='])
```

This currently produces the following colorbar:
[Wrong colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnWiS.png)

As can be seen from the image, only two of the six ticklabels are shown, at the bottom and top of the bar. However, following methods used by others, I expect that `ticks=np.arange(6)` evenly spreads the six labels over the colorbar, before changing the tick labels to the specified string values.

I'm looking for a quick-and-dirty way to fix this, as this is the only visual map I need to make. I've been looking around for hours now without any success in solving this, so please help this beginner programmer.

Comment: Colorbars range from 0 to 1. You can calculate where to put the ticks based on the number of colors.

Comment: Which matplotlib?   Colorbars should no longer go 0-1 on more recent versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes for the ticks are in a range from 0 (bottom) to 1 (top).
Dividing the space evenly into 6 parts will mark the bottom of each color region. Adding half of it will be nicely in the center. Therefore, `ticks=np.linspace(0,1,6,endpoint=False) + 1/12`. Or, equivalently, `ticks=(np.arange(6)+1/2)/6`.

You can remove the tick lines by setting their length to zero: `cbar.ax.axes.tick_params(length=0)`.

To get proper `less than or equal`, having the labels in [TeX format](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/usetex.html) is an option. As in `r'$\leq-6$'`.

Some demonstration code:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c_map = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#c7e9b4','#7fcdbb','#ffffff','#41b6c4','#225ea8','#253494'])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_map)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, 6, endpoint=False) + 1/12, label='Change in user population')
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([r'$\leq-6$', r'$\geq-1$', '$0$', r'$\leq3$', r'$\leq6$', r'$\geq7$'])
cbar.ax.axes.tick_params(length=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example colorbar]

Comment: `≤` and `≥` would do as well. (Python strings are unicode!)