# Generating just a colorbar with labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to generate just a colorbar in matplotlib to go with a series of clustermaps, following [this guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html).

Here is my current code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,8))
cmap = mpl.cm.inferno
bounds = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5],
    # labels=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    cax=ax)
```

But I would like to add labels to each of the ticks. How do I do this? `colorbar()` doesn't recognise any `label`-style arguments.

This problem is different to those answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749741/matplotlib-colorbar-change-ticks-labels-and-locators) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957843/spread-custom-tick-labels-evenly-over-colorbar): I am generating *just* a colorbar, and so using methods like `fig.colorbar.set_ticklabels()` do not work.
I have tried

```
mycb = fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5],
    cax=ax)

## opt 1
mycb.set_ticklabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

## opt2
mycb.ax.set_yticklabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

And neither produce labels on the ticks of my colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs for Colorbar class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar) tell us, Colorbar can take a `Formatter` as one of the arguments (namely, `format`). The Formatter that takes a sequence of labels is called `FixedFormatter`, so this code would suffice:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedFormatter
mycb = fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5],
    format=FixedFormatter(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']),
    cax=ax)
```

The result is shown below:

[image: The colorbar with labels]

Answer (score 0):

Both of your options work if you pass your list of ticks as an argument of `set_ticklabels` or `set_yticklabels`  like this :

`mycb.set_ticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])`

or

`mycb.ax.set_yticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])`